# Visualforce page error display

Tags: visualforce, trigger

How to display the error message from a trigger to a custom visualforce page?

```
 public PageReference save()
    { 

        Student__c stud=new Student__c();
        stud.Firstname__c=student.Firstname__c;
        stud.Lastname__c=student.Lastname__c;
        stud.Address__c=student.Address__c;
        stud.Collegename__c=student.Collegename__c;
        stud.Branchname__c=student.Branchname__c;
        stud.Contact_Number__c=student.Contact_Number__c;
        stud.Date_Of_Birth__c=student.Date_Of_Birth__c;
        stud.Gender__c=student.Gender__c;
        studentlist.add(stud);

        try
       {
         if(studentlist!=null)
          {
            insert studentlist;

          }
       }
         catch(Exception e)
          {
          Apexpages.addMessage(new Apexpages.message(ApexPages.Severity.Error,e.getMessage()));

          }


     return null;
    }
```

i tried using this code but it does not display the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `<apex:pageMessages/>` to display error messages on visualforce page.

> Refer [apex:pageMessages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageMessages.htm)

This component displays all messages that were generated for all components on the current page, presented using the Salesforce styling.

Comment: i tried that too .do i need to write anything in side the <apex:pageMessages/>?

Comment: no need to write inside that

Comment: sir is my controller class correct? Its still not showing the error message

Comment: Make sure that an error is being thrown (easy way is to `insert new Student__c();`, usually fails since theres required fields or expected values), and that your `save` method rerenders your page messages.

Comment: why do we need to throw the error? we are already passing the message in  addMessage()

Comment: @NaveenSinghrajput you can throw custom validation message during saving. Also, any errors during insert can be shown to user. Here is the parameter type is error, it can be information, based on type of exception you want to show the user

Comment: sir can you please give some example

Comment: you can take a look my post http://santanuboral.blogspot.in/2017/10/visualforce-webservice-callout.html